# How to customise the activities tab listing

Tags: developer, 4.7, hooks, 4.6

I used to hack the Activities BAO to change the search results to make the subject line something more useful; i.e. extract other data from particular activity types and auto-create a summary in place of the actual subject.

I'm doing an upgrade and realised what a royal maintainance [PITA](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pita) this has become :-)

I thought I could implement [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/) but I've tried from a Drupal module and also from an extension created for the job but it does not appear to be being called for the tab selector? Is there another way? I've tried this on 4.6 and 4.7.

I might not be explaining which bit I need to customise very clearly, so here's a diagram:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can't realy customise the main activities tab. However there are several other options to create other tabs which show activities which do allow more customisation.

- [Activity Tabs extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/activitytabs/) written by me, this offers a reasonably easy way to add tab(s) with filtered lists of activities and allows you to choose which fields (inc. custom) you want displayed.
- [Data Processor extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor) this is very flexible/powerful, but a bit more of a learning curve (well worth it!)
- [Extended Reports extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) - I've not used this but I believe it allows its reports to be embedded as tabs on a contact record.

Comment: You may want to take alook at this extension as well: https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.fastactivity

Answer (score 0):

The [hook_civicrm_summary](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_summary/) might help you?

Comment: Thanks Erik, but I don't think that hook is called when presenting the Activities Tab activities listing.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were referring to the activities tab in the contact summary? Alternative is to create a copy of the report in an extension as described in the **add a report** section of https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/.

Once you have copied the report all you have to do is use the alterRow function to update the search results.

Comment: Hi and thanks again :-) I've updated the question with a picture to show which bit I'm referring to. It's the listing of activities that you see when you visit a contact's record and click Activities. Accessing this does not seem to fire `hook_civicrm_summary` nor `hook_civicrm_searchColumns` on 4.6 (not tried 4.7 yet).

Comment: Try https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_tabset/ ?

Comment: That's for editing the list of tabs, not the content of the tabs :-( Thanks though.

Comment: I guess there is nothing else than updating the page in an extension.....